# Restkit 0.10.0 & ios 6.1 - objectLoaderWithResourcePath:delegate method not making http call

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, restkit

My ios code (using Restkit 0.10.0) works perfectly well in iPhone **5.1** Simulator. However, the same code does not seem to work on iPhone **6.1** Simulator.

In the code below, [objectLoader send] gets called & I see that the call gets added to RKRequestQueue. However, **no http call is made & the activity indicator keeps spinning endlessly.**

```
-(void)myMethodCall:(NSString*)myparam1 password:(NSString*)myparam2{
RKObjectMapping* wsReturnMapping = ... //assume some complex mapping logic lives here

RKObjectLoader *objectLoader = [objectManager objectLoaderWithResourcePath:@"/somevalidurl" delegate:self]; //this line shows a deprecation warning
objectLoader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
objectLoader.objectMapping = wsReturnMapping;
objectLoader.params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:myparam1, @"myparam1", myparam2, @"myparam2", nil];
[objectLoader send];
}
```

I also tried these approches to make the http call (but none worked):

**Alternate approach 1:**

```
    [objectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/somevalidurl" usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {
    loader.delegate = self;
    loader.method = RKRequestMethodPOST;
    loader.objectMapping = wsReturnMapping;
    loader.params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:myparam1, @"myparam1", myparam2, @"myparam2", nil];
}];
```

**Alternate approach 2:**

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:myparam1, @"myparam1", myparam2, @"myparam2", nil];
NSString *resourcePath = [@"/somevalidurl" appendQueryParams:dict];
[objectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:resourcePath delegate:self];
```

**Questions:**

1) Did anyone get Restkit 0.10.0 to work with iOS 6.x?

2) Any idea why [objectLoader send] is not making the http call? (works for iOS 5.x)

3) If upgrading Restkit is the only option, can I still leverage the **objectMapping** I have? In other words, I couldn't find an example in the more recent Restkit where objectMapping is used.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. The problem seems to happen whenever I switch between iphone 5.1 simulator to 6.1 simulator. I stuck to the original approach. The solution that worked for me is
1) uninstall the app from the simulator *and*

2) clean & rebuild the project.

Wonky - but works.